# Выбор MBaaS системы

Tags: клиент-сервер

Доброго времени суток. 
Я сейчас работаю над клиент-серверным приложением. Будет передача данных с сервера на клиент и обратно. И писать сервер самому с дизайном, функционалом и т/д довольно долго и сложно. Решил обратиться к готовым решениям так называемым MBaaS системам. В общем вопрос: какую систему лучше расматривать? Может кто работал с подобными, подскажите какая наиболее гибкая, что бы можно было менять под свои нужды. 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассматривайте ту систему, с которой вы работали и у вас есть опыт. Если опыта нет, рекомендую использовать nodejs на сервере.

Варианты готовых клиент-серверных приложений :

- https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-express
- https://github.com/kacole2/express-node-mongo-skeleton  : a simple CRUD + REST skeleton for Express + Node + Mongo
- https://github.com/SUDIP2222/Nodejs-Mongodb-CRUD : crud & search using node js , mongodb , express , swig
- https://github.com/garrylachman/ElectroCRUD : приложение на electron (даёт возможность с помощью html, css, javascript делать кроссплатформенные приложения)